# PrimeNg css not working

Tags: html, css, angular, primeng

I can get `<button pButton type="button" class="ui-button-danger"></button>` but it won't style it. I've linked the primeng.min.css in my index.html. But I'm assuming my `.angular-cli.json` file is faulty since the style section is empty.

Edit:
Console error says: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) on the `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css" />` But I've double checked, its there.

Comment: there is no `PrimeNg` in `angularjs `so please change your tag from `angularjs` to angular as its only present in `angular`

Comment: Refer this link getting primeng styles https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/setup

Comment: I've followed the setup guide, I get the following error in console: GET http://localhost:4200/node_modules/primeui/primeui-ng-all.min.css when trying to link it in my index.html

Comment: Bad tagging... PrimeFaces? Please learn the technology you are using

Comment: How is you your project build. Are you using webpack?. If you are using Angular CLI you need to add the styles in the styles sections as: `"styles": [
  "../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css",
  "../node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css",
  "../node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/omega/theme.css",
  //...
],`

Answer (score 6):

You only want to have entries in styles.css like below

```
@import '../node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css';
@import '../node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/nova-light/theme.css';
@import '../node_modules/primeicons/primeicons.css';
```

And there is no entries required in the styles array of angular.json